# HTML Tags problem in Amazon Buyer-Seller Messages

Tags: html, django, amazon-web-services, html-email, amazon-ses

So I am trying to send emails on behalf of the seller to the buyer (Buyer-Seller messages) via the SES email service and it's working good.

The problem is I can't send HTML formatted email. it looks good when I sent it to my email but it will display tags if I do it for the buyer and check that in the amazon messages it will display HTML tags [check link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2a9u.png).

```html
Dear valued customer
<br />
<br />
Thank you for placing an order with us. Please check the attached invoice for your order ID# XXXXX for Volutz USB C Cable 2M Long USB Type C Cable Nylon Braided Durable Charger for Samsung Galaxy S10 S9 S8 A40 A50 A70, Huawei P30 P20, Google Pixel, OnePlus, Nintendo Switch and other USB-C Devices, . <br />
Should you encounter any issues with your order please reply to this email and tell us about how we can make it right.
<br />
We aim to reply to any inquiry within 24h on normal working days.
<br />
<br />
Have a wonderful day,<br />
XXXXXX
```

I am using Django DRF and SES to send those emails. Do I have to encode something here or something else? can someone please help me?

Comment: same here. but it should be possible what you try since they have this: https://sellercentral.amazon.de/help/hub/reference/200415980?locale=en-US